# How to use android Device native camera..?

Tags: android

I am developing an app where i want to use device native camera.i.e. i want to use the exact camera which the device will show when we click on camera option from device including widgets like front camera option etc. i saw one app in android market which exactly doing this. Can any one help me??

Thanks,
Ram.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to save the image in a folder, then this is the easiest way:

```
 try {
    //where to save the image

                File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "foldername" + File.separator);
                root.mkdirs();
                sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
                 outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
                startCameraActivity();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }



    protected void startCameraActivity() {



            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 101);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if(requestCode==101 && resultCode==-1)
            {
                try
                {

            //use that file here


                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.v("OnCameraCallBack",ex.getMessage());


                }
            }
```

If u want to save it in default location:

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
           startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 101);
 @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if(requestCode==101 && resultCode==-1)
            {
                try
                {

            //use that file here


                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.v("OnCameraCallBack",ex.getMessage());


                }
            }
```